# Can you help me identifying this circa 1910 airplane with tail number 72?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Circa 1910 airplane with tail number seventy two

[(Click for larger image)

[image: Circa 1910 airplane with tail number seventy two]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr7MG.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

It is a Wright, allright, but more probably an EX. The EX was a modified Model R, which in turn was a modification of the Model B. The R and the EX were single seaters, whereas the B would seat two.

Picture of a Model B replica, as taken from its [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Model_B) article:
[image: Picture of a Model B replica]

Picture of a Model EX, taken from [this](http://www.wright-brothers.org/Information_Desk/Just_the_Facts/Airplanes/Model_EX.htm) site.
[image: Picture of the "Vin Fizz", a Wright Model EX]

The EX was the model used by [Cal Rodgers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calbraith_Perry_Rodgers) for his epic transcontinental flight. Note the lengthened tail and the closer wings, which allowed to reduce rigging wire and, thus, drag. The "72" shows the same features, so I think it is a Wright Model EX.

Comment: Really appreciate all the help. I am so curious what the "72" is indicative of and what field it was in (empty grandstands in background) but I fear this may never be known. Thanks again guys :)

Comment: @VerticalLiquid: It is obvious from marks in the corners that the picture was in an album - do you still have the album? This might give more context.

Comment: Unfortunately I am an old photo collector and this was purchased by itself. I would love to have that album however ;)

Comment: @VerticalLiquid: It's good to know that collectors like you value those historic documents - if it weren't for you, the picture might not exist anymore. Not everyone takes so much care to preserve historic collections like [Dean Putney](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/deanputney/experience-world-war-i-through-a-german-officers-p?lang=de), after all.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words Peter. It can be an expensive hobby but worth it. I find myself burning up the "whale oil" many nights going through my albums.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Looks very much like a **Wright Model R**. Some information can be found [here](http://www.wright-brothers.org/Information_Desk/Just_the_Facts/Airplanes/Model_R.htm), a picture from that site below:</strike>

[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [wright-brothers.org](http://www.wright-brothers.org/Information_Desk/Just_the_Facts/Airplanes/Wright_Airplane_images/Model%20R/1910_Model_R_Simms_on_display.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Looks very close, but the "72" has a bigger wing: Outside of the props, the Model R has only one pair of struts, but 72 has two.

Comment: @PeterKämpf indeed, you appear to be right.